# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine DLL

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am getting error "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll" missing. From where I can download the DLL. I have installed sap CrystalDecisions but it is giving same problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the SDK at http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824. Be sure you get the right architecture. It sounds like you've already done that. In your project you should click on the DLL in References and set Copy Local to true so that the DLL will also be found on your production machine. If that's not working, I need a little more information about what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean by right architecture? I have already set the Copy Local to true. Error : Error The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There is a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of the installer, I was saying to make sure you got the right one for your machine. Try creating a new console project, and CrystalReports.Engine dll and instantiate a new ReportDocument object. If that works keep adding to it by importing a report and running it. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Even though I have downloaded and installed the latest Service Pack, I can't find any of the `Crystal*` DLLs. Where should they be?

Answer (score 3):

You can install it by going to **Tools > NuGet package manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution** Packages in ASP.NET in VS 2014.  (Sample- you can create a webform and right click and you can find manage NuGET and install it). Even I had the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the DLLs in one of these folders after you have installed it.

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32